# Invalid Arguments - cannot convert Anonymous Type#2

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to subtotal a list, whereby certain columns need to be summed or averaged while others are not relevant for subtotalling e.g. the stock names.

I'm getting an error

> "The best overloaded method match for 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(AnonymousType#1)'
>   has some invalid arguments Argument '1': cannot convert from
>   'AnonymousType#2' to 'AnonymousType#1'"

when running this in Sage 200 Query Builder and can't see what I'm doing wrong.

If I try it in Linqpad it tells me "The name 'cxt' does not exist in the current context"

Any ideas? Thanks!

---

```
var q = from d in cxt.K3_StockProfitMarginByCustomers
select new
{
    d.CustomerAccountName,
    d.CustomerAccountNumber,
    d.Code,
    d.Name,
    d.Profit,
    d.QuantitySold,
    d.TotalCost,
    d.TotalRevenue,
    d.MARGIN,
    d.SLCustomerAccountID,
    d.SOPOrderReturnID,
    d.SOPOrderReturnLineID
};

q = q.Distinct();

var l = q.ToList();
var summary = new 
{ 
   CustomerAccountName = "",
   CustomerAccountNumber = "",
   Code = "",
   Name = "", 
   Profit = (Decimal)q.Sum(o => o.Profit),
   QuantitySold = (Decimal)q.Sum(o => o.QuantitySold),
   TotalCost= (Decimal)q.Sum(o => o.TotalCost),
   TotalRevenue= (Decimal)q.Sum(o => o.TotalRevenue),
   MARGIN = (Decimal)q.Average(o => o.MARGIN),
   SLCustomerAccountID=(String)"",
   SOPOrderReturnID=(String)"",
   SOPOrderReturnLineID=(String)""
};

l.Add(summary);

return l.AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem is with your collection.

```
var q = from d in cxt.K3_StockProfitMarginByCustomers

select new
{
d.CustomerAccountName,
d.CustomerAccountNumber,
d.Code,
d.Name,
d.Profit,
d.QuantitySold,
d.TotalCost,
d.TotalRevenue,
d.MARGIN,
d.SLCustomerAccountID,
d.SOPOrderReturnID,
d.SOPOrderReturnLineID
};
```

This will create anonymous type object as querable and when you do

```
q = q.Distinct();
var l = q.ToList();
```

It create collection of Anonymous Type#1

Now your code initialize another object summary which is anonymous type as there is no way to identify that it is same as created in first query so it create summary as annonymous type#2. Now you are adding that to first typeof collection l which cause error.

Solution:
Create strongly type class that contain all property and use that

first query and leter for summary.

select new yourclass {
   // All property
}

// Create collection
var summary = new yourclass(){ // Assign propery }
// Add summary to collection.

This will solve your problem.

This is complete example

```
// Create new CS file with Name MyClass
public class MyClass
{
  public string CustomerAccountName {get; set;},
    public string CustomerAccountNumber {get; set;},
      public string Code {get; set;},
      public string Name {get; set;},
      public string Profit {get; set;},
      public int QuantitySold {get; set;},
    public double  TotalCost {get; set;},
    public double TotalRevenue {get; set;},
    public double MARGIN {get; set;},
    public int SLCustomerAccountID {get; set;},
    public int SOPOrderReturnID {get; set;},
    public int SOPOrderReturnLineID {get; set;}
}


//
var q = from d in cxt.K3_StockProfitMarginByCustomers
select new MyClass()
{
   CustomerAccountName= d.CustomerAccountName,
   CustomerAccountNumber = d.CustomerAccountNumber,
   Code = d.Code,
   Name = d.Name,
   Profile = d.Profit,
   QuantitySold= d.QuantitySold,
   TotalCost = d.TotalCost,
   TotalRevenue= d.TotalRevenue,
   MARGIN = d.MARGIN,
   SLCustomerAccountID= d.SLCustomerAccountID,
   SOPOrderReturnID= d.SOPOrderReturnID,
   SOPOrderReturnLineID= d.SOPOrderReturnLineID
};

q = q.Distinct();

var l = q.ToList();
var summary = new MyClass()
{ 
   CustomerAccountName = "",
   CustomerAccountNumber = "",
   Code = "",
   Name = "", 
   Profit = (Decimal)q.Sum(o => o.Profit),
   QuantitySold = (Decimal)q.Sum(o => o.QuantitySold),
   TotalCost= (Decimal)q.Sum(o => o.TotalCost),
   TotalRevenue= (Decimal)q.Sum(o => o.TotalRevenue),
   MARGIN = (Decimal)q.Average(o => o.MARGIN),
   SLCustomerAccountID=(String)"",
   SOPOrderReturnID=(String)"",
   SOPOrderReturnLineID=(String)""
};

l.Add(summary);

return l.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Hi there thanks so much for replying. I'm a bit of a newbie and still struggling to understand the solution. I've spent hours trying to understand but not got anywhere :( Would it be possible that you show me by amending my query that incorporates your points?

Comment: 1. Create Class in C# that contain all proties that you select in query. ( MyClass is classname)
2. from d in cxt.K3_StockProfitMarginByCustomers

select new MyClass()
{
CustomerAccountName = d.CustomerAccountName,
d.CustomerAccountNumber, // do like above for all properties
d.Code,
d.Name,
d.Profit,
d.QuantitySold,
d.TotalCost,
d.TotalRevenue,
d.MARGIN,
d.SLCustomerAccountID,
d.SOPOrderReturnID,
d.SOPOrderReturnLineID
};

Answer (score 2):

The two anonymous types are not the same. The properties might have the same names but probably not the same types, they most have both of those to be considered the same type.
   You should consider creating your own class and use that instead.